# What does the prefix L"..." stand for in GCC C without #including wchar?

Tags: c, types

That is, why does `unsigned short var= L'ÿ'` work, but `unsigned short var[]= L"ÿ";` does not?

Comment: Do you mean to say `unsigned short some_variable_name = L'ÿ'`? Because otherwise, that isn't valid C.

Comment: yes, that's right. I just mean to know what the L means. Thanks.

Comment: from the spec: "A *character string literal* is a sequence of zero or more multibyte characters enclosed in double-quotes, as in **`"xyz"`**. A *wide string literal* is the same, except prefixed by the letter **`L`**."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`L'ÿ'` is of type `wchar_t`, which can be implicitly converted into an `unsigned short`. `L"ÿ"` is of type `wchar_t[2]`, which cannot be implicitly converted into `unsigned short[2]`.

Answer (score 5):

`L` is the prefix for wide character literals and wide-character string literals. This is part of the language and not a header. It's also not GCC-specific. They would be used like so:

```
wchar_t some_wchar = L'ÿ';
wchar_t *some_wstring = L"ÿ"; // or wchar_t some_wstring[] = L"ÿ";
```

You can do `unsigned short something = L'ÿ';` because a conversion is defined from wchar_t to short. There is not such conversion defined between wchar_t* and short.

Answer (score 2):

`wchar_t` is just a `typedef` to one of the standard integer types. The compiler implementor choses such a type that is large enough to hold all wide characters. If you don't include the header, this is still true and L'ß' is well defined, only that you as a programmer don't know what type it has.

Your initialization to an integer type works because there are rules to convert one into another. Assigning a wide character string (i.e the address of the first address of a wide character array) to an integer pointer is only possible if you guess the integer type to which `wchar_t` corresponds correctly. There is no automatic conversion of pointers of different types, unless one of them is `void*`.

Answer (score 1):

Chris has already given the correct answer, but I'd like to offer some thoughts on why you may have made the mistake to begin with. On Windows, `wchar_t` was defined as 16-bit way back in the early days of Unicode where it was intended to be a 16-bit character set. Unfortunately this turned out to be a bad decision (it makes it impossible for the C compiler to support non-BMP Unicode characters in a way that conforms to the C standard), but they were stuck with it.

Unix systems from the beginning have used 32-bit `wchar_t`, which of course means `short *` and `wchar_t *` are incompatible pointer types.

Answer (score 0):

For what I remember of C

- 'Y' or whatever is a char and you can cast it into an int and therefore convert it into a L,
- "y" is a string constant and you can't translate it into a integer value

Comment: `unsigned short var[]` is not an integer value. It's an array of `short`s. :-P