# Is long string literal's type long int*?

Tags: c, string-literals, wchar-t

According to the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3772179/673852), a literal like `L"test"` has type `wchar_t[5]`. But the following code with GCC seems to say something different:

```
int main()
{
    struct Test{char x;} s;
    s="Test"; // ok, char* as expected
    s=L"Test"; // ??? I'd expect wchar_t*
    return 0;
}
```

Here's how I compile it (gcc 5.2, but same results are with 4.5 and 4.8):

```
$ gcc test.c -o test -std=c99
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:4:6: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct Test’ from type ‘char *’
     s="Test"; // ok, char* as expected
      ^
test.c:5:6: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct Test’ from type ‘long int *’
     s=L"Test"; // ??? I'd expect wchar_t*
      ^
```

Apparently, instead of the expected array of `wchar_t` I get array of `long int`. What's wrong here?

Comment: But on Linux wchar_t is 32 bit, in some architectures  it may even be just a typedef for long int.

Comment: `struct Test{} s;` doesn't make sense. Structs must have at least one member. Please present code that compiles.

Comment: `wchar_t` is not a built-in type. It is an implementation defined type, that happens to be equivalent to a `long int` on your system. On my system, it's just a plain old `int`.

Comment: @2501 if I presented the code which compiles, I'd never find out the type of the literal. It's intentionally crafted to give a meaningful error.

Comment: On my windows I get `...assigning to type 'struct Test' from type 'short unsigned int *'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type wchar_t is not a fundamental type, like char. It is an implementation-defined synonym of an integer type<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 7.19 Common definitions 2.)
wchar_t which is an integer type whose range of values can represent distinct codes for all
members of the largest extended character set specified among the supported locales;